# Facebook login : Same Facebook KeyHash for two different apps

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-login, android-keystore

I am trying to set facebook login for two different apps.
It works on one of them, but not on the second one.

When I print keyhashes for both of them, like this in RegisterActivity :

```
    println("REGISTER ACTIVITY")
    try {
        val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                "com.discodery.android.zestore",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
        for (signature in info.signatures) {
            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
            md.update(signature.toByteArray())
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT))
        }
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {

    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {

    }
```

Both of the apps give me the SAME keyhash.

Facebook gives me a `SERVER_ERROR` and I am 99% sure the problem come from here.

How to have two different keyhashes for facebook login ?

Comment: check package name..

Comment: @JayNirmal package name are different too, in the gradle, in the manifest, and in the code above, as well as facebook app id

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my boss removed me from the "Developer" on the Facebook app console, and strangely it worked.
No idea why thought.